# ATL Transformation: include a third Metamodel

Tags: transformation, eclipse-emf

i want to check in an ATL transformation if an element is a type of another metamodel, that is neither the source nor the target metamodel. (In this case JavaModelMM).

This is the error message:
org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.VMException: Cannot find reference model JavaModelMM

Does anyone how to "include" other models?

Thanks a lot

```
-- @nsURI JavaModelMM=http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/Java/0.2.incubation/java
-- @nsURI Javapp=http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/Java/Composition/0.1.incubation    /javaApplication
-- @nsURI SMM=http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/SMM/1.0.Beta2/smm


module JavaApp2LOC;
create Metrics: SMM from JavaApplication: Javapp;

rule name {
    from
        region: Javapp!JavaNodeSourceRegion (
            region.javaNode.isMethodDeclaration()
        )
    to
        loc: SMM!NamedMeasure (
            name <- region.javaNode.toString()
        )
}


helper context OclAny  def: isMethodDeclaration() : Boolean = 
    if self.oclIsTypeOf(JavaModelMM!MethodDeclaration.oclType()) then true
    else false
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to list the third one in the from clause of the create statement.

```
-- @nsURI JavaModelMM=http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/Java/0.2.incubation/java
-- @nsURI Javapp=http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/Java/Composition/0.1.incubation/javaApplication
-- @nsURI SMM=http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/SMM/1.0.Beta2/smm
-- @nsURI ECore=http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore

module JavaApp2LOC;
create Metrics: SMM from JavaApplication: Javapp, anotherInput: ECore;
```

Note that you can also specify multiple target models.